# Bizarre SF short - Magazine Of Fantasy and Science Fiction?

Tags: story-identification

I am pretty sure this story appeared in F&SF - it was definitely during the late '60s/early '70s. Two scientists are strolling through what appears to be a zoo. They look down into a concrete pit containing several people. These people are barefoot, wear rags and live in filth but they have been brainwashed into thinking they are a typical middle-class 20th century American family. When the husband 'goes to work' he stands in the corner and pretends to operate a machine. When Grandpa dies they dump his body into a box and then sit on it, thinking it is a sofa and they are watching TV. The scientists discuss this for a while (it was some kind of sociological experiment) and then go on their way, unaware they are barefoot, filthy and wear rags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

["The Adjusted"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53902), a short story by [Kenneth Bulmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Bulmer), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, June 1966](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61216), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v030n06_1966-06_PDF/page/n53/mode/1up).

The beginning:

> On this morning as they went down to the pens the mild early sunlight gentled with soft
> radiance the broken brickwork and gaping concrete so that for a mocking moment the labyrinth assumed a semblance of normality. The two men walked delicately along the raised ramparts between the pens looking down through each transparent roof.
>
> "The zoom they've designed on my new cine camera is fantastic — a recommended Best Buy." The elder of the two withdrew his foot sharply as he kicked a protruding stump of ferro-concrete. "What a frightful bore all this is, Rodney!" He spoke pettishly, like a man
> roused from an absorbing game to attend a broken fuse. "Every time I come here there are less people to care for."
>
> "But we must care, Charles, surely?" The younger man tended to hang a half-body's distance in rear of his companion. "After all . . . Look at the poor darlings! One does try to remember they are human . . ."

The middle:

> The man stood up and walked carefully towards a corner of the pen. He stood facing into the angle of the walls and his body and hands moved occasionally, the bedraggled hem of his clothing knuckling the floor.
>
> "Grandma's quiet this morning, Mum." The remaining Robinsons continued sitting on their boxes, their gruel bowls empty on the harsh floor.
>
> The mother hushed her eldest. "Now you leave your grandma alone, Estelle! She's just having a little nap. Go and watch the telly."
>
> Obediently the three children turned as one to face a blank concrete wall. Mildew grew a roseate whorl. Their faces blanked, smooth and effortlessly becoming tuned receptors. The woman sat humped on her box. A dribble of porridge plopped to the floor.

The ending:

> Rodney stood beside Charles with an exaggerated motion of his legs. Charles held both hands out in front of him rounding on the empty air.
>
> "I like the feel of the velvet steering ring," he said moving his hands smoothingly. "Adds a spot of class."
>
> The two old men tottered gently away, their porridge textured garments wrapping them like shrouds, across the concrete to their own pens.